# Can you link to a FB page from an iOS app and have it go to the FB App if it exists?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I would like to include a link in my app that will open the page in the FB app if it exists on the device, otherwise it opens it in Safari. I'm not talking about a way to do it with code - the code is already in place.

The app has a "news" page and each news item has a link. The link is downloaded with the news data and displayed in the app. I would like to have the FB app open if the user has it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used something like this in the past

```
    NSString *fblink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://page/%@", facebookAccount];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fblink];

    //Open in safari if fb app is not installed
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url]) {
        //fanPageURL failed to open.  Open the website in Safari instead
        NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/FANPAGEADDRESSHERE"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: webURL];
    }
```

Comment: These do not seem to work for me with iOS6 and an older version of the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Yup, iOS6 broke a lot of the facebook url linking. Currently, I only need to support public pages, so I do a graph API call on the username to get the facebook ID of the page then open in safari with `http://facebook.com/FACEBOOK_ID_HERE`. Sorry I can't help any more, haven't looked any further into it.

Comment: you have to use 'profile' instead of 'page' even if you are linking to a page and not a profile :/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on URL schemes.

http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/12/using-app-url-schemes-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Quick note for anyone trying this after the iOS 6 change, they have changed it so page no longer works. Try using profile instead.

Comment: You should have post a comment to say that